# Locking with synchronized block vs Explicit Locking

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, monitor, illegalmonitorstateexcep

I implemented a barrier in java using `synchronized` block and got `IllegalMonitorStateException`. On replacing that `synchronized` block with explicit locking with `lock.lock()` and `lock.unlock()` in `await` method, the code works as expected.

I could not figure out what exactly is happening different between the cases. Can someone help me with understanding this?

```
package org.example;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Barrier {
    private int count;
    private int threshold;
    private final Lock lock;
    int toBeReleased;
    Condition incrementCondition;
    Condition releaseCondition;
    public Barrier(int threshold) {
        this.count = 0;
        this.toBeReleased = 0;
        this.threshold = threshold;
        this.lock = new ReentrantLock();
        this.incrementCondition = lock.newCondition();
        this.releaseCondition = lock.newCondition();
    }
    public void await () throws InterruptedException {
-        synchronized(lock) {
+           lock.lock();
            while (count == threshold) {
                incrementCondition.await();
            }
            ++count;
            if (count == threshold) {
                toBeReleased = threshold;
                releaseCondition.signalAll();
            } else {
                // Note the usage of await/signal and not wait/notify
                releaseCondition.await();
            }
            toBeReleased--;
            if (toBeReleased == 0) {
                count = 0;
                incrementCondition.signalAll();
            }
+           lock.unlock();
-        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final Barrier barrier = new Barrier(3);

        Thread p1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Thread 1");
                    barrier.await();
                    System.out.println("Thread 1");
                    barrier.await();
                    System.out.println("Thread 1");
                    barrier.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
            }
        });

        Thread p2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    System.out.println("Thread 2");
                    barrier.await();
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    System.out.println("Thread 2");
                    barrier.await();
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    System.out.println("Thread 2");
                    barrier.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
            }
        });

        Thread p3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                    System.out.println("Thread 3");
                    barrier.await();
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                    System.out.println("Thread 3");
                    barrier.await();
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                    System.out.println("Thread 3");
                    barrier.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
            }
        });

        p1.start();
        p2.start();
        p3.start();

        p1.join();
        p2.join();
        p3.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: `synchronized` goes with `Object#wait(...)`, `Object#notify()`, and `Object#notifyAll()`. Whereas `Lock` goes with `Condition`. The two systems aren't "mixable" (i.e., you can't do `synchronized (someJavaUtilLockObj)` and then expect `someConditionObj.await()` to work).

Comment: You never should never use `synchronized` on a `Lock`.

Comment: Please clarify your example: it includes commented out synchronised statements on your explicit lock references, yet you say you replaced one with the other?

Comment: I have added - and + signs in statements to make it diff like instead of commenting out the replaced code. Hope this clarifies the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Two Locking Mechanisms

As a general rule, if you're using `java.util.concurrent.locks`, then do not use `synchronized` in the same context. The same is true in reverse. The two are separate mechanisms and are not designed to interact with each other.

### synchronized

All objects in Java have an implicit "monitor". When you `synchronize` on an object, you acquire that monitor. While you hold the monitor, you can call the following methods on the corresponding object instance:

- `Object#wait()`, `Object#wait(long)`, `Object#wait(long,int)`
- `Object#notify()`
- `Object#notifyAll()`

Trying to call these methods on an object instance without holding that object's monitor will result in an `IllegalMonitorStateException` being thrown.

### java.util.concurrent.locks

Unlike `synchronized`, this API is not built into the language. It does not care or know about the implicit monitor. Instead, a `Lock` maintains its own state regarding which thread owns it, and which threads are waiting to acquire it. To acquire and release a `Lock`, you must go through the methods defined by the `Lock` interface; you cannot use `synchronized`.

One of the things the `java.util.concurrent.locks` API did was extract the concept of a "condition" out into its own object. This makes `Lock` a "factory" for `Condition` objects, and a `Condition` remains associated with its source `Lock`. Thus, a `Condition` knows whether a thread calling one of its methods owns the corresponding `Lock` or not. And similar to `Lock`, waiting and signaling must be done via the methods of `Condition`; you must not use the methods defined by the `Object` class.

Trying to call methods on a `Condition` (or trying to unlock a `Lock`) without owning the `Lock` (via a call to e.g., `Lock#lock()`) will result in an `IllegalThreadStateException` being thrown.

Note this API also provides `ReadWriteLock` and `StampedLock`, as well as the building blocks needed to write your own lock implementations.

## Your Code

You essentially have the following:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Foo {

    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition condition = lock.newCondition();

    public void bar() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (lock) {
            condition.await();
        }
    }
}
```

This is mixing the two locking mechanisms together, which will not work properly. You `synchronized` on the `lock`, thus acquiring the object's implicit monitor. But then you call `await()` on the `Condition` object. You may own the *monitor*, but from the point-of-view of the `Lock` and `Condition`, you do not own the *lock*. Hence an `IllegalThreadStateException` being thrown.

You should use *either* `synchronized` *or* `java.util.concurrent.locks`. The following is two versions of a "barrier" that waits for a certain number of threads to be waiting before letting them all continue on. One version uses `synchronized`, the other version uses `java.util.concurrent.locks`.

#### `synchronized` version

```java
public class SynchronizedBarrier implements Barrier {

    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private final int threshold;
    private int count;

    private boolean thresholdReached;

    public SynchronizedBarrier(int threshold) {
        if (threshold <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("threshold <= 0");
        this.threshold = threshold;
    }

    @Override
    public void await() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (thresholdReached) throw new IllegalStateException("threshold already reached");

            count++;
            if (count == threshold) {
                thresholdReached = true;
                lock.notifyAll();
            } else {
                while (!thresholdReached) {
                    try {
                        lock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        count--;
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### `java.util.concurrent.locks` version

```java
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class LocksBarrier implements Barrier {

    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition isThresholdReached = lock.newCondition();
    private final int threshold;
    private int count;

    private boolean thresholdReached;

    public LocksBarrier(int threshold) {
        if (threshold <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("threshold <= 0");
        this.threshold = threshold;
    }

    @Override
    public void await() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lockInterruptibly();
        try {
            if (thresholdReached) throw new IllegalStateException("threshold already reached");

            count++;
            if (count == threshold) {
                thresholdReached = true;
                isThresholdReached.signalAll();
            } else {
                while (!thresholdReached) {
                    try {
                        isThresholdReached.await();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        count--;
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Both versions are single-use. If the threshold is reached, then no more threads can call `await()` without an exception being thrown. I also implemented it so that a waiting thread that's interrupted is subtracted from the number of waiting threads. That choice was arbitrary. You could leave `count` unmodified. Or maybe you could have all other non-interrupted threads throw a `BrokenBarrierException` (similar to how [`CyclicBarrier`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) does it).